# Firebase Facebook login: An invalid API Key was supplied in the request

Tags: swift, facebook, firebase, facebook-login

Trying to get Facebook login to work with the new Firebase, but I keep getting this error: "An invalid API Key was supplied in the request."

```
     facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"], fromViewController: self) { (login, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Facebook login failed. Error \(error)")
        } else if login.isCancelled {
            print("Facebook login was cancelled.")
        } else {
            let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
            let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(accessToken)

            if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
                user.linkWithCredential(credential) { (sup, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                        return
                    }
                }
            } else {
                FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        // ERROR COMING FROM HERE
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                        return
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the instructions from Google: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158862?hl=en to get or create the API KEY of your iOS App.

Then you need to grab this **API KEY** and put it in the **GoogleService-Info.plist** as the:

**Key:** API_KEY

**Value**: the api key that you got.